# Angular directive which isn't present in the DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to have a directive that I can use for grouping `ng-if` or `ng-switch-when` like:

```
<empty ng-switch-when="expression">
  ... Lots of little DOM nodes ...
</empty>
```

If I just do

```
.directive('empty', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
  };
})
```

then it works, but still has an `<empty>` in the DOM, to which CSS selectors are applying (particularly problematic are the direct child selectors). So can I get it out of the DOM completely?

For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FBFHS7A66he73xA2wlNy?p=preview should have a red link.

Comment: Add property replace : true in your directive along with restrict : 'E'

Comment: @nikhil.agw  `return {    restrict: 'E',    replace: true  };` still has the `<empty>` in the DOM

Comment: `replace` is deprecated. I believe that directives are present in the DOM by definition. You would have to do some magic, e.g. removing the directive element from the link function of the directive (using a timeout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.directive('empty', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            transclude(scope, function (content) {
                element.replaceWith(content);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Or you can likewise use scope.$parent (depending on which scope you need), e.g.

```
transclude(scope.$parent, function (content) {
```

Working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dqlVqbZC33SKA7TunZ1O?p=preview).

Comment: In the comments above @Sulthan mentioned replace is deprecated. Is that true? And is there a replacement?

Comment: @PaulTarjan you can actual remove the replace property in this case, as there is no template being used (which would be the DOM structure replacing the directive element). The above is just manually handling the transclusion through the transclude method, and in this case replacing the whole base element with the transclusion (nested) content.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: One other thing to be cautious of is that if another directive is defined on the element (e.g. an attribute based directive) has an isolated scope defined then the 'empty' directive above will also share that isolated scope I believe. Hence it may even be safer to define the empty directive with an isolated scope, and then have the transclude function use scope.$parent. 
This of course will depend on your need however, so test this for yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Here is an example of something to be cautious of:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dqlVqbZC33SKA7TunZ1O?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.directive('empty', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.replaceWith($compile(element.contents())(scope));
    }
  };
})
```

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/2cbpiWOIW5EUuuDjkbB5?p=preview

Comment: Here is the updated plunker that will work - http://plnkr.co/edit/haZ3e1xVzMBAAkiDu3Te?p=preview

Comment: element.replaceWith(element.html()); has to be updated with element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));

Comment: I provided simple answer as per OP's requirement. Ofcourse if we have any model to passed to the directive then we have to process if further.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli when I inspect the DOM using either of your plunkers I still see `<empty>` in the DOM. This manifests by blocking direct child selectors in CSS. Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FBFHS7A66he73xA2wlNy?p=preview

Comment: @PaulTarjan: I dont see the `<empty>` tag here http://plnkr.co/edit/2cbpiWOIW5EUuuDjkbB5?p=preview. I am using the latest angularJs 1.4.x in the plunkr. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli ah nice! That's closer. Can you preserve the scope with your solution? http://plnkr.co/edit/bYoYznnKS9c7TXsBp7HX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason that you cant make it a comment directive?

As in `restrict: 'M'`

and then:

`<!-- directive: empty -->`

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/guide/directive

scroll down to directive types for more info

Comment: Doesn't 'C' mean class? The restrict option is typically set to:

'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name

Comment: Of course you are right @Paul Tarjan. Its 'M' not 'C', and has been amended.

Comment: But how will 'M' help me? My goal is to group many things that share a `ng-switch-when` or an `ng-if` or whatever so I don't have to put it on every single one of them.

Comment: Yep, sorry. Misread the question. You could probably patch the ng-switch source to be able to a be a comment directive, but that will probably cause even more problems haha.

Comment: @Iain If you wish to delete your answer, there is a button for that - otherwise, please do not attempt to destroy the post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
app.directive('empty', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var content = $compile(element.html())(scope);
            element.parent().prepend(content);
            element.remove();
        }
    };
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ttqO91Dcr4Y9INuyJUlO?p=preview

Note: if you want to make sure the element is exactly at the same place, you can use jQuery's `insertBefore` instead of `parent().prepend`

Answer (score 0):

For `ng-if` you can use `ng-if-start` and `ng-if-end`, much like `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
<p ng-if-start="true">First visible paragraph</p>
<p>Another visible paragraph</p>
<p ng-if-end>Last visible paragraph</p>
<p ng-if-start="false">First hidden paragraph</p>
<p>Another hidden paragraph</p>
<p ng-if-end>Last hidden paragraph</p>
```

which can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/c7C0WDx93rMSo3i9Taro?p=preview

For `ng-switch` you can use `ng-switch-when-start` and `ng-switch-when-end`:

```
<div ng-switch on="selection">
   <div ng-switch-when-start="a">A 1</div>
   <div>A 2</div>
   <div ng-switch-when-end>A 3</div>
   <div ng-switch-when-start="b">B 1</div>
   <div>B 2</div>
   <div ng-switch-when-end>B 3</div>
 </div>
```

which can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/cRjHcmjODBzwm1BjeSuO?p=preview

To achieve this, I suspect `ngIf` and `ngSwitchWhen` must use the [`multiElement`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-multielement-) option when they're defined.